# How can I build login and registration system in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am making a login and registration system in react native. I have 13 screens in total out of which 4 screens needs person not to be logged in and in 4 screens people need to be logged in and the remaining 5 are independent of the logged in status.

I have successfully fetched the details into the application and stored it in AsyncStorage.I have then used two different types of approaches.

1. I have used the function 'check' [ tried this in render and component did mount and constructor ] mentioned below to perform whether the user data persists in the AsyncStorage and if exists, I have redirected the user to 'Home' screen.
   This works however whenever , I go back to login page, I am not redirected.
2. I have made 3 different navigators one that is independent, one that requires logged in and one that requires not to be logged in. This creates a problem I am not able to navigate from one navigator to another navigator's specific screen.

   ```
   let check = AsyncStorage.getItem('user').then(res => {
     res = JSON.parse(res);
     typeof res == 'string'
       ? alert(res)
       : this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
   ```

   . });

I got two questions here.

1.Is there any way using which I can navigate from one navigator to a specific screen in another navigator ?
2.What is the best way to achieve my required result ?

Comment: Building an Authentication Flow with React Navigation - https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/building-an-authentication-flow-with-react-navigation-fb5de2203b5c

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [createSwitchNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html) you can achieve this [Auth Flow](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html)

**Set up our navigators**

```
import { createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

// Implementation of HomeScreen, OtherScreen, SignInScreen, AuthLoadingScreen
// goes here.

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen, Other: OtherScreen });
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen });

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
));
```

**Implement our authentication loading screen**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  AsyncStorage,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._bootstrapAsync();
  }

  // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
  _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

    // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
    // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
    this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
  };

  // Render any loading content that you like here
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ActivityIndicator />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```